# Multidimensional array acting strangely

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
char number[5000]="37107287533902102798797998220837590246510135740250\
46376937677490009712648124896970078050417018260538\
.....more numbers.....";
char numbers[100][50];
main()
{
    int x,z;
    extern char numbers[100][50],number[5000];
    for(x=0;x<100;x++)
    {
        for(z=0;z<50;z++)
        {
            numbers[x][z]=number[50*x+z];
        }
    }
    printf("%s\n",numbers[0]);
}
```

So the thing is I have this code and for some reason numbers[0] is being the same as number. Isn't numbers[0] supposed to be the first 50 characters first.I can't figure this out.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why wouldn't `numbers[0]` and `number[0]` be the same...

Comment: number[0]='3' ? 
while numbers is a multidimensional array or am I wrong here?

Comment: Strings in C (as printed with the `%s` format) are zero-terminated.

Comment: @PascalCuoq Thanks yeah.The guy below answered that and it's just that I'm forgetting these stuff. I think I need to get more used to C :D

Comment: Note that you can make char arrays that are not strings, and then you don't have to zero-terminate them. But you must not print them with `%s` then, you have to write your own function based on `printf("%c",…);`, using a loop to print the 50 characters.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: You can use, e.g., `printf("%.*s", array_size, array)` to print non-terminated arrays.  It's potentially flawed (depending on your intent) as it treats an embedded `'\0'` as the end of a string (it's a `%s` variant after all).  But the implementor writing `printf()` must avoid calling `strlen()` (I used `memchr` instead) when handling a limited-precision `"%s"` directive, so it is *safe*, at least.

Comment: Oh thanks for that.So I didn't need to terminate them after all since it was not my intention to print them in the first place :| 
I just print them to check if it's going alright but still thanks for all the advice today :D

Comment: @torek I was just writing my own interpreter of format strings recently (in the context of making a C interpreter that detects undefined behaviors as they happen) and `%.XXXs` is on my TODO-list. These formats are incredibly expressive, which is good for the programmer but quite a bit of work on the implementation side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are printing `numbers[0]` with a `%s` directive.  This takes the address of the first `char` (i.e., a value of type `char *`) pointing to the first character of a "string": a sequence of `char`s terminated by a `'\0'`.

The `numbers[0]` array contains 50 non-`'\0'` `char`s, and immediately after that (at `numbers[1]`) there's another non-zero `char`.  So `%s` has no idea where to stop.  (Technically this causes undefined behavior when you run off the end of the first array into the second one, but in practice, C systems just keep going.)

Note that if you set all 50 `char`s to non-zero values, there is no room left for a `'\0'` byte.  You'll need to set aside 51 `char`s to hold 50 printable `char`s and the one final `'\0'`.  Alternatively, you can use a structure other than a C string, such as a counted-array (the things that `memcpy` and `memcmp` deal with), but unless you want to allow `'\0'` bytes in your `char` array, that's usually too much work.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yes, the precision-limited %s is mentioned in the comments on the question itself.  I dislike using a literal count as it is fragile: change the array size and you have to find and fix all `%.50s` formats too.  Annoyingly, `%.*s` requires an `int` value, not a `size_t` one, so it's error-prone in a completely different way (although both gcc and llvm can catch format/argument mismatches in `printf`-like functions, at least).

Answer (score 5):

```
for(x=0;x<100;x++)
    {
        for(z=0;z<50;z++)
        {
            numbers[x][z]=number[50*x+z];
        }
    numbers[x][z+1] ='\0'; //Did you miss this ?
    }
```

Comment: Oh Thanks a lot. :D... I think it'll really take me some time to get used to C.

Comment: ...and don't forget to make `numbers[100][51]` large enough to hold the zero terminator!

Comment: @HasanSaad, this is the convention of a string in C. It's called a **NULL terminator**.

Comment: @FerdinandBeyer Yeah Thanks. I already did that  :D
And Jacob thanks for the information :D
It'll take me some time to get used to C as back in Python which I'm used to I didn't do stuff like this :p

Comment: Why not `memcpy(numbers, number, sizeof number)`?

Comment: @H2CO3,Well I'm new to C and I never knew of this function before.Thanks and I think I'll google this function after I'm done with the code I'm doing.Thanks for your advice :D.

Comment: @H2CO3, it was originally one string and he wanted to split it into multiple strings of 50 characters. It would not produce the result we wanted.